# Ошибка при использовании GregorianCalendar. Как исправить?

Tags: java

Учу java и экспериментирую. Второй час не могу понять, почему код генерирует ошибку. Что исправить?

```
public class MyApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stopwatch stw = new Stopwatch();
    stw.setStartTime();
    System.out.print(stw.startTime);
}
}

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
class Stopwatch {
GregorianCalendar startTime;
void setStartTime() {
    this.startTime.setTimeInMillis(123);
}
}
```

> Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at
> Stopwatch.setStartTime(Stopwatch.java:7)
>
> at MyApp.main(MyApp.java:5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строка

```
GregorianCalendar startTime;
```

не создаёт объект `GregorianCalendar`, она создаёт ссылку, которая в данный момент ни на какой объект не указывает. Поэтому в строке

```
this.startTime.setTimeInMillis(123);
```

возникает ошибка, ведь `startTime == null`, а вызвать метод на `null` нельзя. Для того, чтобы это предотвратить, необходимо повесить на эту ссылку объект `GregorianCalendar`:

```
GregorianCalendar startTime = new GregorianCalendar();
```